# How to use assert with optional value?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to add an if statement for assert?

Like, if this value is not null, it shouldn't be less than zero.

Something like:

```
class Spinner extends StatefulWidget {
  const Spinner({
    super.key,
    this.durationInSeconds = 6,
    required this.child,
    this.stopAfter,
  }) : assert(if(stopAfter == null) stopAfter > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ternary if operator and make sure you're using the right condition. You want to check the range of `stopAfter` is it *isn't* `null` as you say in the text of your question. You can't read the value of a variable if it's `null`.

```dart
assert(stopAfter != null ? stopAfter > 0 : true);
```

The reason why your method would not work, even if it were syntactically allowed, is that you don't provide a condition for when `stopAfter` is `null`. If `stopAfter` is `null`, the assert needs to know how to handle it.

Comment: Also `assert(stopAfter == null || stopAfter > 0);`. You never need a boolean literal as one of the branches of a boolean-typed conditional expression, it can be rewritten using `||` or `&&` and some negations.